# Meaning of the gradient equations when solving the least squares problem

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

tl;dr Why can we say that we are minimizing the sum by making the gradient equal zero?

In linear regression using least squares as an estimator, one must minimize $ \sum_{i=0}^{n} (y_i - f(x_i))^2 $ to find the coefficients $\beta$ of $f$, a linear combination of $\beta_j \Phi_j(x)$, $j = 0..m$. I know the answer is to solve

$$ \nabla \sum_{i=0}^{n} (y_i - f(x_i))^2 = 0 $$

I understand that the minimum value the sum can assume is zero and that the gradient produces a vector of $m$ partials which gives $m$ equations with $m$ coefficients, enabling me to solve that linear system of equations and find the coefficients.

However, if $y$ cannot be exactly represented by $f$, such is the case of fitting a dataset generated by a polynomial of degree $k$ with $f$ a polynomial of degree $k - 1$, then the sum is *never* zero. So what are we saying when we equal the gradient equations to zero ($\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_j} r_i^2 = 0, j = 0..m$)? As I understand a gradient of zero means no change (in any direction), so in this case it would mean that the sum of the errors squared is *constant*, not zero, right? Why can we say that we are minimizing the sum by making the gradient equal zero?

Answer (score 1):

You are not saying that the gradient is identically zero, you are identifying a point where it is zero. When your problem is regular enough, this is a necessary condition for a minimum, because if the gradient is nonzero at some point, then you can move a small distance in the opposite direction of the gradient to reduce the function.

Comment: Necessary, but is it sufficient? Can't that point also be a local maximum?

Comment: @Alex True but I think the additional analysis of classification is beyond the scope of the OP.

Comment: Well can you point me to an analysis on the subject? I did some research since your answer and I'm impressed the answer is always the same: "The gradient must be zero at the minimum thus it minimizes S" - but no one mentions it's zero in other extrema as well. Or is it?

Comment: @Alex Typically the sum of squares of residuals is a convex function of the parameters $\beta_j$, in which case the gradient being zero is a sufficient condition for minimality. But that depends on the exact form of $f$. If the underlying problem is nonconvex then the situation becomes problem-specific, I think.